# Why does this absolutely positioned element follow the flow?

Tags: css

I just stumbled across something baffling:

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
    background:lime;
    height: 100px;
}
.parent div {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Parent
    <div id="test">Child</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the yellow "Child" rectangle is below the word "Parent". Why? The way I understand the default values for `top` and `left` are `0`, so the element should position itself at the upper-left corner of the parent. In fact, if I remove the text `Parent` or add `top: 0` to the child element, this is what happens. But why does in this case the absolutely positioned box follow the flow?

Comment: _“The way I understand the default values for top and left are 0”_ – no, they are not; the default value for both is `auto`. And yes, that has a different effect here, than explicitly setting `0` would. Basically the implicit `top` value becomes the offset the element _would_ have from its position ancestor’s top border in normal flow.

Comment: @CBroe, man, you should have posted this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe! I found what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute position is still anchored in the flow of the content of its parent element when position is `auto` (which is the default). If you move the child element to the beginning of the parent, you see what you had expected (see snippet below). You can avoid that by adding `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
    background:lime;
    height: 100px;
}
.parent div {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div id="test">Child</div>
    Parent
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, finally found the answer I was looking for! Thanks to @Cbroe for pointing me in the right direction:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

> If all three of 'top', 'height', and 'bottom' are auto, **set 'top' to the static position** and apply rule number three below.